# All-day events are not created correctly in Office 365

Tags: api, rest, office365

I am trying to export some events to a calendar in Office 365 through their REST API, https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#EventoperationsCreateevents.

I set the `IsAllDay` to true, and set the start and end to midnight in UTC.

The payload looks like this:

```json
{
  "Body": {
    "Content": "Agenda",
    "ContentType": "HTML"
  },
  "End": "2015-02-01T00:00:00Z",
  "ShowAs": "Busy",
  "Start": "2015-01-30T00:00:00Z",
  "ChangeKey": "X2+akAeClEa0OJ8r6nC5QgABW30vaQ==",
  "Location": {
    "DisplayName": "Vesterbrogade"
  },
  "Subject": "Updated title",
  "IsAllDay": true
}
```

That looks fine, and if I GET the event again, the payload comes back as set. However when I go to outlook.office365.com the event now spans 2 days, instead of 1 as intended. The duration however appears as 1 day. Unclicking the "all day" in Outlook reveals the problem. Since I am in Central European Time, I'm one hour ahead of UTC. The start shows as 2015-01-30 01:00 and the end as 2015-02-01 00:59. So underneath the covers it doesn't seem to be stored as an all day event in my timezone.

When you use f.ex. EWS, you normally set the timezone of the meeting, however that doesn't appear to be possible.

I have tried to give the start and end with timezone information, but I get a 400 telling me it has to be supplied in UTC. So as far as I can tell there is nothing I can, expect hope that Microsoft fixes this. Or am I missing something?

EDIT: The event actually appears correctly in Outlook for Mac, so perhaps this is only a problem in the OWA at outlook.office365.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API now supports time zones. What you would want to do here is not specify your `Start` and `End` as UTC (indicated by the 'Z' prefix on the end), but instead specify it in your time zone. You would then set the `StartTimeZone` and `EndTimeZone` values to "Central European Time". So something like this:

```json
{
  "Body": {
    "Content": "Agenda",
    "ContentType": "HTML"
  },
  "Start": "2015-01-30T00:00:00+01:00",
  "End": "2015-02-01T00:00:00+01:00",
  "ShowAs": "Busy",
  "Location": {
    "DisplayName": "Vesterbrogade"
  },
  "Subject": "Updated title",
  "IsAllDay": true,
  "StartTimeZone": "Central European Standard Time",
  "EndTimeZone": "Central European Standard Time"
}
```

Comment: It was pointed out to me that the API does in fact now support time zones, so I've changed my answer :).

Comment: Awesome! I search all over the place for that, as I felt it must be there somewhere, but I couldn't find it in any of the Office 365 docs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem! It isn't in the documentation yet, so I didn't even know about it at first either! I'll be working on getting it added.

Comment: Didn't help for me

Comment: @JasonJohnston, If an event is allday for a day, then it will be the same date and time, right? Then should I add a day manually to the end date?

Comment: If an event is allday for a day, should I add a day manually to the end date?
And after creating an event like that, then should I subtract a day to get the event? What is the correct all day event?