# All day event spans on two days in Outlook 365 Calendar API

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-calendar

When I create a one day, all-day event with the Outlook 365 Calendar REST API, I get an event spanning on two days unless I specify the proper time zone...

I have the same two days span problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982218/all-day-events-is-not-created-correctly-in-office-365). Is there a way to send the query without the fields StartTimeZone and EndTimeZone? It is a redundant information with the Start and End fields that contain the time zone as well, and somehow "Mountain Standard Time" (GMT-7) does not work in SF, but "US Mountain Standard Time" does, although both are in the doc, both at GMT-7, and I do not know what happens in the rest of the world when the time zone string is ambiguous like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way it is supposed to work - in Outlook all day event spans one day only in a particular time zone. In all other time zones it spans 211 days.

Comment: I am not unhappy with one day, all-day event spanning on two in other time zones, it makes sense in a way. My problem with StartTimeZone and EndTimeZone -apart from the fact that it is redundant with Start and End and that it is a potential source of mispelling mistakes- is that I do not know which timeZone I should use. I thought having a -7 hours offset from UTC would allow me to use indifferently "Mountain Standard Time", "Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)" and "US Mountain Standard Time", but only the first one works for me... How to chose the good one? What do I do wrong?